# test if two strings are different in rake file

Tags: ruby, rake, string-comparison

In a rake task, I want to execute a commande conditionally, but the string comparison does not work as expected. Here is what I have in my rake task:

```
puts "compare ('#{fetch(:stage)}' != 'production')"
if fetch(:stage) != 'production' then
  puts 'they are different'
end
```

I expect that `puts 'they are different'` is skipped, since the two strings are equal. But the statement is executed nonetheless, as the output proves:

```
compare ('production' != 'production')
they are different
```

I guess this is because the first is a variable of type sting while the second is a constant ? Obviously string comparisons work differently in ruby. What is the 'ruby way' to do it ?

Comment: `fetch(:stage)` probably returns `:production`, i.e. a _symbol_.

Comment: @Stefan You are right: changing `!= 'production'` to `!= :production` works. How to compare strings with symbols to test if they are equal ore not ?

Comment: Well, strings and symbols aren't equal. But you could convert one into the other, e.g. `'production'.to_sym == :production` and `'production' == :production.to_s` both return `true`.

Comment: It's always a bad idea to check equality by interpolating in a string... For example, `1 != "1"` and `true != "true"`. Types are important. (This is ruby, not PHP!) Two objects don't necessarily need to be of the same class in order to be considered equal, but you shouldn't just ignore that information.

Comment: I'd strongly advise using a debugger, like `pry`, instead of relying on putting `puts` statements in your code.

Comment: I always use built-ins like `puts` / `p` / `inspect` for debugging 

Comment: @stefan thanks, you give me the keywords for my next searches. I always wondered what these special :strings were, that can become variable names...

Comment: @tomlord Oh, it is PHP! We deploy our PHP projects with Capistrano :D. Until now my ruby knowledge was limited to basic capfile and stage configuration :)